Accessing values using panda
I am working on getting the dipole energy of the interactions with aminoacids and a macrodipole. I have only used those aminoacids that have ionic tendencies and can have a charge when in water. I have a table where I have the distances between the aminoacid and the macrodipole for each residue, that i use to calculate the potential and then the dipole energy. I believe that in my current code I am not accessing correctly the data, and i don't know how to do it. Never used panda before and I don't know if I am establishing wrong conditions.
The main code is:
def main():

    sequence = input("Enter your sequence: ").strip().upper()
    while True:
        try:
            temperature_kelv = float(input("Enter your temperature in K: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a numeric value for temperature.")
             
    # convert kelvin to celsius
    temperature_cels = temperature_kelv - 273.0
    
    # extract segments after obtaining sequence
    segments = extract_segments(sequence)
    
    for segment, n_cap, c_cap in segments:
        print (f"Segment: {segment}, N-cap: {n_cap}, C-cap: {c_cap}")

And this is the dipole function that I am implementing to get the dipole energy.
    charge_dict = {
    'D': -1,  # Aspartate
    'E': -1,  # Glutamate
    'K': 1,   # Lysine
    'R': 1,   # Arginine
    'H': 1    # Histidine
     }

# Function to calculate dipole energy
def dipole_energy(segment, dipoleN_df, dipoleC_df, charge_dict):
    dipole_energies = []
    for i in range(len(segment)):
        residue = segment[i]
        
        if residue == ['D', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'H']: 
            if i == 1:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N-Cap"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C-Cap"]
            if i == 2:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N1"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C1"]
            if i == 3:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N2"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C2"]
            if i == 4:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N3"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C3"]
            if i == 5:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N4"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C4"]
            if i == 6:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N5"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C5"]
            if i == 7:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N6"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C6"]
            if i == 8:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N7"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C7"]
            if i == 9:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N8"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C8"]
            if i == 10:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N9"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C9"]
            if i == 11:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N10"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C10"]
            if i == 12:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N11"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C11"]
            if i == 13:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N12"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C12"]
            if i == 14:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N13"] 
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C13"]
                
            
            # Convert distances from angstroms to meters
            distance_N_m = distance_N * 1e-10
            distance_C_m = distance_C * 1e-10
            
            # Compute the electrostatic potential at the residue 
            potential_N = (1 / (4 * np.pi * epsilon_0)) * (Q * L / distance_N_m**2)
            potential_C = (1 / (4 * np.pi * epsilon_0)) * (Q * L / distance_C_m**2)
            
            # Get the charge of the residue
            charge = charge_dict.get(residue)
            
            # Compute the dipole energy
            dipole_energy = charge * (potential_N + potential_C)
        else:
            dipole_energy = 0.0
        
        dipole_energies.append(dipole_energy)
    
    return dipole_energies

The distance_N and distance_C csv are documents that look like
res N-cap, N1, N2, N3 ...
E.   1.     0.5.  3.8 ....
D .....

and so on.
Can someone help me access the data correctly? How am I supposed to do it?
Thank you

Your question needs to augment your minimal reproducible example by providing sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.

How is Pandas involved? BTW - your repeated if statements involve unnecessary comparisons - use elif for subsequent tests.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You were actually quite near getting it right, but as was mentioned in the comments, many of your conditions were unnecessary. I created here a function that does the job, as well as sample data for that:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

epsilon_0 = 8.854187817e-12  
Q = 1.6e-19  
L = 1e-9  

charge_dict = {
    'D': -1,  # Aspartate
    'E': -1,  # Glutamate
    'K': 1,   # Lysine
    'R': 1,   # Arginine
    'H': 1    # Histidine
}

dipoleN_data = {
    'res': ['D', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'H'],
    'N-Cap': [1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0],
    'N1': [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
    'N2': [3.8, 3.6, 3.5, 3.4, 3.3],
    'N3': [4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4],
    'N4': [5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4]
}

dipoleC_data = {
    'res': ['D', 'E', 'K', 'R', 'H'],
    'C-Cap': [1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.1],
    'C1': [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0],
    'C2': [3.9, 3.7, 3.6, 3.5, 3.4],
    'C3': [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5],
    'C4': [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]
}

dipoleN_df = pd.DataFrame(dipoleN_data).set_index('res')
dipoleC_df = pd.DataFrame(dipoleC_data).set_index('res')

def dipole_energy(segment, dipoleN_df, dipoleC_df, charge_dict):
    dipole_energies = []
    
    for i, residue in enumerate(segment):
        if residue in charge_dict:
            if i == 0:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, "N-Cap"]
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, "C-Cap"]
            else:
                distance_N = dipoleN_df.at[residue, f"N{i}"]
                distance_C = dipoleC_df.at[residue, f"C{i}"]
            
            distance_N_m = distance_N * 1e-10
            distance_C_m = distance_C * 1e-10
            
            potential_N = (1 / (4 * np.pi * epsilon_0)) * (Q * L / distance_N_m**2)
            potential_C = (1 / (4 * np.pi * epsilon_0)) * (Q * L / distance_C_m**2)
            
            charge = charge_dict[residue]
            
            dipole_energy_value = charge * (potential_N + potential_C)
        else:
            dipole_energy_value = 0.0
        
        dipole_energies.append(dipole_energy_value)
    
    return dipole_energies

sequences = ["DEKRH", "RHKDE"]
segments = [(seq, seq[0], seq[-1]) for seq in sequences]

data = []
for segment, n_cap, c_cap in segments:
    energies = dipole_energy(segment, dipoleN_df, dipoleC_df, charge_dict)
    for i, energy in enumerate(energies):
        data.append({
            'Sequence': segment,
            'Residue': segment[i],
            'Position': i+1,
            'Dipole Energy': energy
        })

dipole_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(dipole_df)

which, for all sequences, gives you:
  Sequence Residue  Position  Dipole Energy
0    DEKRH       D         1    -262.644489
1    DEKRH       E         2    -692.917825
2    DEKRH       K         3      22.834586
3    DEKRH       R         4      15.204950
4    DEKRH       H         5       9.685188
5    RHKDE       R         1      84.216996
6    RHKDE       H         2     321.332716
7    RHKDE       K         3      22.834586
8    RHKDE       D         4     -17.542033
9    RHKDE       E         5     -10.846753


